# Is there an algorithm to determine a computer performance?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, cpu-usage

I want to write a C# application that compares the performance of two PCs, and know which PC will perform a task faster than the other.

So is there an algorithm for doing this?
for example ( (NumberOfProcessCurntlyRunning*AvailableRAM)+CPUUsage).

Assuming that we have 2 computers with the same computing and hardware power.

Comment: Do a benchmark test for overall performance: http://www.userbenchmark.com/Software

Comment: You have 2 PCs and you want to know which will run a task faster? Have you tried running the task on the 2 PCs and timing it - pretty sure that will give you the answer...! (Please clarify your question if my response is not what you are looking for)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this. However, I want a clear algorithm that I can code it later on, in an application am working on.

Comment: @Eyadkht I really don't understand what you are looking for. An algorithm is just a sequence of actions, typically executed by a computer. What are you actually trying to do? Please edit your question with your "real-world" problem and add more context...

Comment: @RB sorry if that wasn't clear. I edited the question hope it's better now.

Comment: @Eyadkht Ah! You don't want to know what will run a task faster (as that is impossible to determine without running it) - you want to know which computer has the most available resources to *do* the task (which is determinable!). If your application is mostly CPU bound, then check the [CPU idle time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724907/obtain-total-cpu-time-of-idle-process-in-windows-similar-to-task-manager), and if it needs lots of memory, then check the memory. If it needs lots of network bandwidth, or disk writes, then check those values. Unfortunately, your question as-is is...

Comment: ...probably too broad to answer as it requires specific knowledge of your application to answer. However, the code to look up any of the values I mentioned is easily findable, so hopefully that is a sufficient pointer?

Answer (score 3):

As I agree that there is no general purpose algorithm to determine the overall performance of a computer, there are some algorithms that are being used by scientists to create more reliable benchmarks for their papers. So if you implement another solution targeting the same problem you can tell if it's better then previously discovered ones even tho you are working on a different machine then previous teams.

One example can be a benchmark algorithm dfmax. It will give you in a short time some foggy idea on how fast the current machine is, but it won't take into account RAM that is available. But I think that it could be some start for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't an algorithm to determine overall computer performance. There are lots of things that can affect overall performance.

You should determine what to compare; access to memory, the efficiency of the CPU cache, efficiency of GC, then implement functions for each of them.

If you need a blind test and you don't care any of specific metric then you can run the same function (e.g. quick sort) and log time and compare milliseconds.